# bodyParser middleware not working when adding static route

Tags: node.js, express

I'm a newbie on express, and when I was creating a simple server demo I detected that POST requests were not sent. After doing some experiments I discovered that it was the express.static middleware, that somehow was interfering. I supposed it was a common error, but didn't manage to find a clue. My code is the following:

```
//jshint esversion:6
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import https from "https";

/* jshint ignore:start */
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
/* jshint ignore:end */
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use("/", bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  let name = req.body.name;
  let email = req.body.email;
  let message = req.body.message;

  res.send("POST request to the homepage");
  console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}!`));
```

I'll gladly appreciate any answer or commet :)

**EDIT**: Apparently this error doesn't occur on Firefox, but does on Chrome and Edge

Comment: Shouldn't `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));` be registered with some route? Or at least after all `/` routes?

Comment: `express.static()` does not have any effect at all on POST requests.  It only pays attention to GET requests.  If you want us to be able to help you, then you need to describe your problem in much more detail.  Tell us exactly what URL is being sent to your server, what http method, what you expect to have happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: @Anatoly Like this right?: `app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/public"))`. Didn't work. Anyway, I think that if path is not specified it applies to all requests

Comment: @Anatoly - That is not necessary.  `app.use(fn)` is the exact same as `app.use("/", fn)`.  No difference.  `app.use()` matches any path that starts with the same path  as you pass it.  Since all paths start with `"/"`, it's the same as passing no path.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have a form with action "/". Worked fine (request parameters where printed), but after adding `express.static()` the request wasn't even received. In fact, after looking on dev tools, it wasn't sent either

Comment: @AlejandroAlcántara - Not being sent from the client is a completely separate issue.  You will have to track that down inside the client code, can't address that from the server code.  Perhaps `express.static()` caused a different `index.html` to be sent to the client and that's the root of the problem?   You can either move your `app.get("/", ...)` handler BEFORE the `express.static()` middleware or you can pass the `{index: false}` option to `express.static()` to tell it NOT to serve `index.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured out what was really blocking this.

When adding `express.static()` it loaded the JS for the front-end, which has the following line:

`$(".sendMessageBtn").attr("disabled", "true");`

which disables the submit button. Turns out disabling it also means it can't send anything **BUT** only on chromium browsers. This does not happen on Firefox.

To disable it without causing this mess, you can replace with:

`$(".sendMessageBtn").css("pointer-events", "none");`

Instead of disabling it through HTML, it uses CSS

Answer (score 0):

Based on your symptoms of the POST not even being sent from the client when you added the `express.static()`, I would guess that when you go to the `/` route in your browser, that `express.static()` was picking up an `index.html` from your `public` directory rather than the `index.html` that you wanted from here:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

You can fix that two ways.  Either move this `app.get("/", ...)` route before the `express.static()` route or tell the express.static route to NOT serve `index.html` like this:

```
// set up static file handling, but don't serve index.html for the / request
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public", {index: false}));
```

Comment: I've checked and there's no `index.html` on my `public` directory. I tried both ways you said and didn't work :(

Comment: Then, something is broken in your front-end if it's not sending the request to your server. You will have to gather some debug information on that - there's nothing here in your question that would indicate to us what might be going on.

Answer (score -1):

So the way `express` static file serving works is that you put a `/path` which you want to serve on, and the term `express.static(/path/to/static/folder)` which will be published to the api.

Otherwise your entire application will be static, due to the fact that everything start with `/`.

*See the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) for more info.*

In your case:

```
app.use("/your-static-endpoint", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

---

One more thing about your code. Stuff like **static serving**, **error handling**, **body parsing** are called **middlewares**, so if you want to apply them through the application, you **shouldn't specify a path**, because it might interfere with how `express` handles routing.

Comment: This is really wrong.   `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))` is very common and works just fine.  It only matches files that actually exist in the `/public` directory.  For any other GET or HEAD request that doesn't match a file in the `/public` directory, routing continues just fine onto other routes as it checks for a match and when none is found, it calls `next()` to continue routing.